# The RPC services keeps stopping

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, service, mstsc

For some reason, the RPC service keeps stopping which prevents me from remoting into the server.  When this happens I have to manually make my way to the server to restart it as simply starting the service (which does not complain when starting), does not let me remote into the server.  I have to restart the server manually to be able to remove into the server again.

It seems to be happening a few times a day.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Is anything logged in the Application portion of the Event Viewer?

Comment: What kind of virus checking do you have in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go into the recovery options of that service have you set to auto restart if it fails?

If the service is still causing you issues you could use something like FireDaemon Pro with Fusion - http://www.firedaemon.com/

That way you can restart services over a web interface rather than having to go to the box and reboot.

Comment: The problem is, once the service has stopped, simply restarting the service does not give me the ability to remove into the server.  Even though the service seems to start, it still complains that the RPC service is not running, which stops me from remoting into the server.  So, to resolve the problem, I have to restart the whole server.

Answer (score 1):

The RPC servive can also be revived by restarting the "DNS Client" and "Net Logon" services (provided you can get to the console either physically or via Drac/ILO/KVM or something). This does not solve the underlying problem, but at least you will avoid restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

While it won't fix the underlying problem, you can auto-restart failed services.

1) type Services.msc in your Run command area

2) Right click on the process and click "Properties"

3) Go to the Recovery Tab and set the service to restart on First Failure. You can subsequently choose what you'd like to do for the second and third failure.

This has proved quite valuable to me in that sometimes the services that run my backups will stop working properly - this really helps.

Cheers,

Comment: The problem is, once the service has stopped, simply restarting the service does not give me the ability to remove into the server.  Even though the service seems to start, it still complains that the RPC service is not running, which stops me from remoting into the server.  So, to resolve the problem, I have to restart the whole server.